# Show pages with a specific template when user is logged-in

Tags: 8, theming, routes

I would like to know if there is a way to show an existing node with a custom template if user is logged-in or has a specific role.

I have tried with a custom module route.

```
custom_module.presentation:
  path: '/node/1'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_module\Controller\myController::custom_presentation'
    _title: 'presentation'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'
```

In the page controller, I used the following code.

```
public function custom_presentation() {
        $myVariables = array();

        $build = [
            'description' => [
                '#theme' => 'my_custom_template',
                '#scriptVars' => $myVariables
            ]
        ];
        return $build;
    }
```

It doesn't work, though. What is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: I did a paywall that's basically the same concept. The idea was that there was a "paywall" view mode and it would toggle with full/default based on user login/role status. Took 5 minutes to write :)

Comment: @IvanJaros: Pretty heroic, but how will this help the OP with his issue?

Comment: this is so basic that i don't know what else to write :) .. I guess `'#theme' => \Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated() ? 'my_custom_template__auth' : 'my_custom_template__anon',`

Comment: @ Ivan Jaros - Thank you for your answer  it seems basic indeed but i can not change my template for specific node .. - i do have   page--my-custom.html.twig in my theme folder ... ( i've twig debug) but my output is still page.html.twig ...

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way of providing a custom template for a node that meets certain criteria, is using theme hook suggestions.

You can for example add a custom theme suggestion by implementing [hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.4.x) in a custom module. There you can check whether your criteria are met and add a custom theme suggestion, if they are:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_node_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  if (
    // Do your checks here, e.g authenticated user?
    \Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated()
  ) {
    // Add your custom template here. The following
    // example would apply to 'my-node.html.twig'.
    $suggestions[] = 'my_node';
  }

}
```

Comment: Well thank you for your help , i tried your theme hook suggestions ... but what it does is loading my-node.html.twig inside {{ page.content }} .... do i miss something ? i've read doc and i'm still digging on it

Comment: @JeromeTurpin: This was what I was reading from your question. "show an existing node with a custom template" You can easily adapt the above example by altering the theme "HOOK" to the theme hook you are trying to use with your template. For example "page", or even "html" if you are in need of an entirely different layout. Of course the available `$variables` will vary from theme hook to theme hook and you might have to fetch the current node from the request, if you want to check against node conditions: `$node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node')`